# Why everything placed further than 1.0f are cut in Java3D?

Tags: java, java-3d

I have a little problem with java3d
everything is cut when I position it in distance of 1.0f or more to right or up(example in link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/edltq.png

And it's code:

```
public class Gfx3D extends JFrame {

    Gfx3D(){
        super("światła");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(config);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        add( canvas);

        add(canvas);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        BranchGroup content = getScene();
        content.compile();

        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(content);

    }

    public BranchGroup getScene()
    {
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

        ColorCube cube = new ColorCube(0.3f);

        Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();
        transform.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));

        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup(transform);
        tg.addChild(cube);

        group.addChild(tg);

        return group;
    }

    public Transform3D lookTowardsOriginFrom(Point3d point)
    {
        Transform3D move = new Transform3D();
        Vector3d up = new Vector3d(point.x, point.y + 1, point.z);
        move.lookAt(point, new Point3d(0.0d, 0.0d, 0.0d), up);

        return move;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Gfx3D();
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to get rid of this, I hope someone will help

Comment: Please edit and adjust your tags or include the packages  you are using.  [java] does not have the methods you are using.  You will also get more appropriate help that way.

Comment: You have to adjust the front clip distance and the back clip distance: https://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.0-final/j3dcore/javadoc/javax/media/j3d/View.html#setBackClipDistance(double) https://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.0-final/j3dcore/javadoc/javax/media/j3d/View.html#setFrontClipDistance(double) I advise you to learn the basic concepts of computer graphics, you use a view frustum here. Please indicate which version of Java3D you use.